# CGAffineTransformTranslate Weird Issue

Tags: iphone, cgaffinetransform

I got some weird CGAffineTransformTranslate issue, code is like this

```
- (void)translateTextPosition:(CGSize)size {
NSLog(@"before tx = %f, %f",_textMatrix.tx,size.width);
_textMatrix = CGAffineTransformTranslate(_textMatrix, size.width, size.height);
NSLog(@"tx = %f",_textMatrix.tx);
}
```

But output shows that

```
2011-10-26 18:57:03.351 PDF[62708:b903] Tm tx:48.437599 ty:752.559387
2011-10-26 18:57:03.353 PDF[62708:b903] before tx = 48.437599, 0.345000
2011-10-26 18:57:03.353 PDF[62708:b903] tx = 53.549774
```

That is not the correct result I want? What I expected is tx = 48.782599
Can someone enlighten me what is wrong with this?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to explain matrix mathematics to you? That might be better on the maths stack exchange site. I wouldn't have a clue what the appropriate value should be but it works, so I guess the maths is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying the translate matrix by your existing affine, not the other way around. Use

```
_textMatrix = CGAffineTransformConcat(_textMatrix, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(size.width, size.height));
```